# Best weapon combo for a rogue (Levelling heirlooms)

Tags: world-of-warcraft

First question here, I think this is where I would come to ask such a question.

So I have just started a new char that is a Rogue, now I'm getting geared with heirlooms for faster levelling and just to make life easier (getting these weapons so I don't have to keep getting new ones).

Is there a certain combo of weapons that are best for Rogues? I was thinking 2 daggers but am not sure if that's the best way to go.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/what-is-the-best-weapon-strategy-for-a-rogue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Assassination spec

Two daggers.  You need them for Mutilate and Assassin's Resolve from level 10.  Go get your Scarlet Kris heirlooms.

### Combat spec

Not daggers.  Some abilities reference one strike (Sinister Strike, Revealing Strike, Killing Spree, Mastery).  That strike should be big.  Dagger's one strike is small.  Other abilities are normalized so speed doesn't help (Blade Flurry, Combat Potentcy).  Use Thrash Blade or Mass of McGowen heirlooms.

### Subtlety spec

Daggers allow Backstabs and bigger Ambushes.  However you might not be using Backstab, Hemorrhage gives faster combo point generation.  Faster combo points means more finishers. I find that in current dungeon situations, fights are very fast and backs available - Dagger shines here.  While solo'ing, backs are not as available, or against dungeon bosses, fights are longer and finishers matter more.

Level 63 subtlety rogue vs level 60-63 Zangarmarsh wildlife:

```
Hammer
Ambush hit: 1553-1799 crit: 3281
Hemorrhage hit: 571-711 crit: 1153-1447

Dagger
Ambush hit: 1955-2233 crit: 4140
Hemorrhage hit: 571-731 crit: 1171-1205
Backstab hit: 1175-1341 crit: 2508
```

Knowing this, I would choose Dagger for Subtlety.  Hemorrhage does the same damage either way.  Ambush does 25% more damage with dagger.  If you aren't ambushing and backstabbing, weapon choice doesn't matter.